# Session cookie is reset by ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

My site consists of single aspx page and few resources like images, js and stylesheets. When the page is opened it generates Asp.Net_SessionId wich is used when getting other resources but then the resource resets ASP.NET_SessionId with response. What can be done about this?

```
Default.aspx:
Request:
Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=

Response
Set-Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=pf31rzumimjurdmdhc1qgq45; expires=Tue, 16-Mar-2010 14:21:43 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly

Default.css:
Request:
Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=pf31rzumimjurdmdhc1qgq45

Response:
Set-Cookie ASP.NET_SessionId=; expires=Tue, 16-Mar-2010 14:21:44 GMT; path=/
```

This drives me crazy. It only happens when I'm setting sessionCookie.Expire value. Moreover sometimes it's fine sometimes it like the above description :(

Answer (score 4):

Are you storing anything in the `Session` object? If not, ASP.NET will not persist your session and use a new session ID on each request. The solution is to store some dummy value, e.g.

```
Session("Dummy") = 1
```

before accessing the session ID.

Comment: where should I use this code? I can't put it in ASPX because response from CSS file removes the session.

Answer (score 0):

In global.asax

```
private void Session_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   Session.Add("blerg",1);
}
```

I wasn't able to test.  Also, on IIS6, static files by default are served direct without going though the ASP.NET isapi filter, so if you aren't using wildcard mapping, this is all for naught-- you won't have any session going on for a static file if it doesn't go though the ASP.NET pipeline.  Cassini/VS Dev Server both send all static files through the ASP.NET pipeline.  Off the top of my head I don't know what the default behavior is for static files in IIS7.

Comment: My guess would be that static files are served directly by IIS by default.

Comment: The real answer for IIS 7 depends on the pipeline mode: http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/508/wildcard-script-mapping-and-iis-7-integrated-pipeline/  No need to guess when google knows it.